# htaccess: сделать редирект только доменной зоны

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Казалось простой вопрос, но не могу найти на него ответ. Хочу перенести сайт с одного домена на другой. Название сайта отличается только доменной зоной. Было .ru, стало .com. Хочу чтобы был редирект не просто со всех старых ссылок на главную новую, а чтобы во всех старых ссылках подменялась только доменная зона.

Допустим человек заходит через поиск на сайт по старой ссылке, редирект меняет ему только доменную зону, и он попадает на нужную внутреннюю страницу.

Например с oldsite.ru/contacts на oldsite.com/contacts и так со всеми внутренними ссылками и главной страницей соответственно.

Даже близко не нашел нигде, как это реализовать. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: оба домена на один физический сайт смотрят?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} "oldsite.ru"` какой нить использовать с 302м редиректом на новый домен

Comment: Даже близко не нашел нигде, как это реализовать. Помогаю искать. https://yandex.ru/search/?text=htaccess+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82+%D1%81+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD&clid=2270455&banerid=0500000134%3A5fcba4121aed9400412bb9c7&win=466&lr=219

Comment: Похоже, что вы не внимательно читаете условие. Нужен редирект не на главную страницу нового домена, а чтобы все ссылки редиректили на эти же ссылки, только на новом домене.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Странно что не нашли. На старом домене пишете правило для редиректа

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

И всё.

Правило значит что для **любой** ссылки на текущем сайте нужно сделать редирект на такую же ссылку, но на новом сайте.

По сути при заходе на старый сайт браузер будет получать заголовок Location c новым URL на новый сайт.

Comment: Да. Это работает. Спасибо. И я понял почему у меня не работало. Сайт на вордпресс. И там уже стояли какие то правила, которые не давали нормально работать этому условию. Когда убрал все лишнее, заработало, как нужно.